# Using Python variables in MySQL insert statement

Tags: python, mysql, database, python-2.7

I've been trying for a while now and have look online and can't figure it out.

Variables are `numbers` and `animals`

```
sql = ("INSERT INTO favourite (number, info) VALUES (numbers, animals  )")
cursor.execute(*sql)
conn.comit()
```

Comment: Where did you look online? Did you read [official MySQL Connector documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html)?

Comment: In Python, variable names don't start with an uppercase letter. Name them `sql`,  `cursor`, `conn`.

Comment: I wrote this on my phone and automatically made them upper case.

Comment: @Tom Please go through official documents before posting questions to Stackoverflow , otherwise you ll get block here .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use variables in SQL statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
sql=("INSERT INTO favourite (number, info) VALUES ({},{})".format(numbers,animals))
```

Its always good to use format as per future references.
Check https://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting-operations

Comment: Don't insert parameters into an SQL statement manually. You need proper quoting of the values, and a chosen SQL connector library always provides this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

```
sql = ("INSERT INTO favourite (number, info) VALUES (%s, %s)", (numbers, animals))
```

for safety, always use escape, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should work. Let me know how it works out for you.

> sql=("INSERT INTO favourite (number, info) VALUES ({},{})".format(numbers,animals))

Comment: Thank you for the downvote. Please improve the answer if you think you can!

Answer (score 0):

```
    sql = "INSERT INTO favourite (number, info) VALUES (%s, %s)"
    val = (numbers, animals)
    cursor.execute(sql, val)
    conn.commit()
```

This works I just tested. Also you mispelled commit idk if that was intentional..

incase you dont have the top connection part right here

```
    db = mysql.connector.connect(
            host="localhost",
            user="root",
            password="password",
            database="database"
            )

    cursor = db.cursor()
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is alternative solution which works for me

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
query ="INSERT INTO favourite (number, info) VALUES ('"+ variable1  +"','"+  variable2+"')"
cursor.execute(query)
conn.commit()
```

Comment: This is a very dangerous method, because it doesn't escape anything. Hence, if your variable includes any SQL characters, such as `;`, it will be interpreted as part of the statement. This means your code is now vulnerable to SQL injection. If your variable1 is populated with `; DROP TABLE favourite;`, it would delete the entire table and it's contents.