# Add variable value to mysql columns

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

I'm creating my first small project. I have a connection to the database using mysql-connector.
The problem is when I enter data using the input function, I create variables where I want to enter previously entered values ​​into the database.

I get an error:
`*1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1*`

A part of code:

```py
mycursor = db.cursor()
wartosci_do_bazy = pytanie_mysql, odpowiedz_a, odpowiedz_b, odpowiedz_c, odpowiedz_d, odpowiedz_true_mysql, value_pytanie

sql = "INSERT INTO pytania (tresc_pytania, odpowiedz_A, odpowiedz_B, odpowiedz_C, odpowiedz_D, odpowiedz_true, question_value) VALUES (wartosci_do_bazy)"
mycursor.execute(sql)
db.commit()
```

When I was creating a table:

```py
mycursor.execute(
   "CREATE TABLE pytania (question_id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY Key,"
    "tresc_pytania VARCHAR(255), odpowiedz_A VARCHAR(255),"
    "odpowiedz_B VARCHAR(255), odpowiedz_C VARCHAR(255),"
    "odpowiedz_D VARCHAR(255), odpowiedz_true VARCHAR(255),"
    "question_value INTEGER(255) )")
```

Comment: in your insert command, all the values are not passed for each column

Comment: could you show me example insert command in this example?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
mycursor = db.cursor()
#pytanie_mysql, odpowiedz_a, odpowiedz_b, odpowiedz_c, odpowiedz_d, odpowiedz_true_mysql, value_pytanie

sql = ("INSERT INTO pytania 
(tresc_pytania, odpowiedz_A, odpowiedz_B, odpowiedz_C, odpowiedz_D, odpowiedz_true, question_value) 
 VALUES 
(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
 (pytanie_mysql, odpowiedz_a, odpowiedz_b, odpowiedz_c, odpowiedz_d, odpowiedz_true_mysql, value_pytanie))
mycursor.execute(sql)
db.commit()
```

you can see more in this link: [Using Python variables in MySQL insert statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37405287/using-python-variables-in-mysql-insert-statement)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help!

Solution:

```
        wartosci_do_bazy = pytanie_mysql, odpowiedz_a, odpowiedz_b, odpowiedz_c, odpowiedz_d, odpowiedz_true_mysql, value_pytanie
        print(wartosci_do_bazy)
        sql = ("INSERT INTO pytania (tresc_pytania, odpowiedz_A, odpowiedz_B, odpowiedz_C, odpowiedz_D, odpowiedz_true, question_value) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")
        mycursor.execute(sql, (wartosci_do_bazy))
        db.commit()
```